# Why does the yeoman generator only generate the assets, without the participants and transactions

Tags: angular, blockchain, hyperledger-composer

The sample application only generates the the assets, without the participants and transactions. I am trying to integrate the back-end of the blockchain with the front-end. The front-end only shows the assets. What is causing this?

Comment: What version of Composer are you using ? With v0.19.0 you should have the ability to generate / have forms for assets and participants (transactions are not implemented yet, its a work in progress). https://github.com/hyperledger/composer/releases/tag/v0.19.0

Answer (score 0):

The yeoman generator is a bit limited, it doesn't generate those for you automatically. There are a ton of open issues on the Composer Github to improve it with suggestions like yours. See: [this](https://github.com/hyperledger/composer/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue%20is%3Aopen%20angular)

The transactions and participants are exposed as an API, though. So you can make calls to them, as long as the participant used is correctly authenticated. 
Big tutorial on that [here](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/tutorials/google_oauth2_rest)